How to schedule tasks in multitenant spring app having separate schema for each tenant
I have develop small Spring boot Multi-tenant SAAS application
refer https://github.com/mahaveer3103/multi-tenant-springboot, now i want to schedule some tasks for every tenant like to check password expires or not for each tenant and if expired update db value in tenant schema and sent notification.
I am using TenantContext to resolve tenant from request Header and route request to appropriate tenant database respectively.
please help me how can we schedule tasks
